# cron job to monitor file changes

Tags: search, cron

Instead of manually searching my files for unauthorized code injections, I want to make a cron job that does it for me (i.e. it checks for a changed checksum). I don't know the first thing about how cron job code works. I only know how to set the time interval.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use [ConfigServer exploit Scanner](http://configserver.com/cp/cxs.html), it checks for malware whenever a file is modified using the Watch daemon.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) and incrontab it works like a cron job but instead check for changes to the file system

Comment: Thanks. I've recently found [ConfigServer exploit Scanner](http://configserver.com/cp/cxs.html), it checks for malware whenever a file is modified! And it's by the same company that makes CSF firewall!

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://www.guardio.net website files monitoring